# How to grant access to google appengine page in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a simple app that serves a page, I want this page to be accessible only to a couple of predetermined users already signed into Google. In fact, I want access only through importHTML function in Google Spreadsheets.

How to implement this with minimum fuss? Here's the app:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('/Statement.htm')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/Statement.htm', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

Here's the app.yaml

```
application: *********
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  static_files: Statement.htm
  upload: Statement.htm
```

I've seen this in the tutorial:

```
from google.appengine.api import users

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

        user = users.get_current_user()
```

But who is this "get_current_user"? I don't want any logins, I just want it to be some kind of Google ID that I can check with if/else and serve out error page if it doesn't match one or two allowed names.

Answer (score 1):

You should give them admin permission from your google app engine dashboard - under Administration -> Permissions - and add to your app.yaml file:

**EDIT:**

This is a way to do it using jinja2 template system.

app.yaml file:

```
application: statement
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /statement
  script: statement.app
  login: admin

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

statement.py file:

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class Statement(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('Statement.htm')
        self.response.out.write(template.render())



app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/statement', Statement)],
                              debug=True)
```

Statement.htm file:

`You must have been granted admin permission.`

When you go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/statement` you must login as admin to get there.
All three files are in the same directory. If your python main file has other name you should use that name and the extension `.app` in the app.yaml file:

`script: your-python-file-name.app`

Comment: That doesn't seem to achieve anything. After the addition app.yaml looks like this:   
`version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  static_files: Statement.htm
  upload: Statement.htm

- url: /Statement\.htm
  script: main.app
  login: admin`

Comment: You have it wrong way round. The app.yaml is read top->down, first matching entry is choosen. And your first entry /.* matches everything. Flip these entries.

Comment: @T. Steinrücken I haven't figured out how to properly flip entries yet, meanwhile solution based on jinja2 works, but only in browser, when my google spreadsheet tries to access it via importHMTL it gets "error: The data could not be retrieved. Please check the URL." How do I give admin rights to google spreadsheet? I assumed it tries to access anything on the web as being signed into Google with my credentials. I probably need a different solution to control importHTML type of access. Would granting access to google script based getURL be easier? I can switch the spreadsheet to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Put "login: admin" into your app.yaml and add these user as viewer to the application.
See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, the only problem is that I can't get the right combination of of my statement.py and app.yaml files. If I add login:admin in the handlers for static_files section it gives me an error, if I create a separate handler for "script: main.app" it doesn't change anything, the page is still displayed to anyone. If I change it to "script: statement.py" it throws an error, too.

Answer (score 0):

Since importHTML function does not seem to provide for any kind of authorization I simply changed url handler to a really long string of random numbers (actually passphrase encoded as SHA1).

To the jinja based solution above I added a handler in app.yaml like so

```
- url: /a...................6/.*
  script: spreadsheet.app
```

Where spreadsheet.app points to a spreadsheet.py which is the same as statement.py except for a different url string in webapp2 call and a new class name.

Now people accessing through browser need to be authorized as admin while the long link exists only inside a cell of a google spreadsheet document and so is not left in browser history or anywhere.

I hope it would also not be indexed by Google and not appear in search results.

Maybe not the perfect solution but a passable workaround.